# Slow connection with Cloud SQL when an instance is spin up or started?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, app-engine-flexible

I got a strange issue with Cloud SQL second generation, whenever a new instance spins up or is started, it takes around 8s to connect to the database. Can anyone please suggest the possible solution to avoid this latency? I am using GOOGLE APP ENGINE flexible with Hibernate and `c3p0` connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is expected considering that the Instance has to be started and authenticated. The docs consider the [restart case](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/start-stop-restart-instance#restart) but may be applied to this case as well:

> Restarting an instance
>
> **Restarting an instance drains the connections from the instance and stops it.** Next, instances with an activation policy of Always
>   restart and are ready to accept new connections....
>
> **Note:** Restarting a running instance can resolve some problems with the instance. However, **restarting an instance causes a disruption in
>   service, and empties the instance cache, which results in a temporary
>   reduction in performance.** If you have restarted your instance
>   recently, check the instance logs to ensure it has fully recovered
>   before restarting it again.

Check the link provided above.